# Google Fonts, robot sans-serif do not work

Tags: html, css, font-family, google-fonts

Although I put the links of font-awesome and google fonts, the fonts on the website does not change. I do not know how to fix it. Does anyone know what causes this problem?

contact.php

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en-US">
 <head>
    <title>American Website Design &amp; Development Agency - JOEY NAMIKI DESIGN</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/contact.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick-theme.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 </head>
<body>
<section class="contactSection">
                <h1>Please tell me what kind of design you want to get?</h1>
                <div class="contactForm">
                     <div class="tweet">
                      <h1>We listen all clients</h1>
                      <p>If you have any concerns regards to web, marketing, branding, design and redesign, feel free to ask me. I will give you the estimation.</p>
                      </div>
                      <form method="post" action="send.php"  id="content">
                            <div>*Name<input type="text" name="name" required></div>
                            <div>Company Name<input type="text" name="company"></div>
                            <div>*Phone Number<input type="text" name="phone"  required></div>
                            <div>*Email<input type="text" name="email"  required></div>
                          <div>*Message<textarea type="text" name="message" ></textarea></div>
                        <div><input type="submit" class="send"   value="submit"></div>
                      </form>
                </div>
          </section>
</body>
</html>
```

contact.css

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 2592px) {
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    background: black;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    color: cornsilk;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif, 'PT Sans'sans-serif, Helvetica sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 160%;
}
button {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
}
a {
    font-size: 18px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
h1 {
    font-size: 42px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 120%;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif, 'PT Sans'sans-serif, Helvetica sans-serif;
}
p {
  font-size: 17px;
  line-height: 1.4;
}
}
```

Comment: You just need to add commas between fonts and no need to repeat sans-serif `font-family: 'Roboto', 'PT Sans', Helvetica, sans-serif;`

Comment: @jeprubio Oh okay. That is really kind of you to remove "*" in order not to get any bad review from anyone, then! Thank you. Do you know how we can post sth on stackoverflow although the explanation is short..? I am beginner to use this website. I do not get used to this, yet.

Comment: @DohaHelmy Oh okay. I will do that. Thank you!!

Comment: @JKK No problem. I don't know if there is another way. I think that you can't until you have enough reputation. But there are many of us trying to help when we see things like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
font-family: 'Roboto', 'PT Sans', 'Helvetica', sans-serif;
```

The line states that the first priority is given to Roboto, somehow if that font is not found, PT Sans will be applied. On the third priority, Helvetica is there.

For any reason if these fonts failed to load, we have set sans-serif as the last priority, any supported Sans-serif (Ariel or any other) fonts will be applied.

Comment: @ksilentstorm Can you add an explanation as to why this answer works?